# The output of "yum updateinfo" and "yum check-update" is not the same

Tags: centos, rhel, package-management, yum

Why I am getting an empty list when running `yum updateinfo`:

```
$ yum updateinfo
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.ate.info
 * epel: fedora.tu-chemnitz.de
 * extras: centos.mirror.ate.info
 * updates: ftp.rezopole.net
updateinfo summary done
```

However, when executing `yum check-update`, I see some available updates:

```
[root@instance /]# yum check-update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |  28 kB  00:00:00
 * base: centos.crazyfrogs.org
 * epel: mirror.karneval.cz
 * extras: centos.crazyfrogs.org
 * updates: mir01.syntis.net
base                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  | 3.6 kB  00:00:00
epel                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  | 5.4 kB  00:00:00
extras                                                                                                                                                                                                                                | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
updates                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
(1/7): base/7/x86_64/group_gz                                                                                                                                                                                                         | 165 kB  00:00:00
(2/7): epel/x86_64/group_gz                                                                                                                                                                                                           |  90 kB  00:00:00
(3/7): extras/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                                                     | 153 kB  00:00:00
(4/7): epel/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                                                         | 6.9 MB  00:00:00
(5/7): base/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                                                       | 6.0 MB  00:00:03
(6/7): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                                                                                                                                                         | 1.0 MB  00:00:04
(7/7): updates/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                                                    | 5.8 MB  00:00:03

nss.x86_64                                                                                                                      3.44.0-7.el7_7                                                                                                        updates
nss-softokn.x86_64                                                                                                              3.44.0-8.el7_7                                                                                                        updates
nss-softokn-freebl.x86_64                                                                                                       3.44.0-8.el7_7                                                                                                        updates
nss-sysinit.x86_64                                                                                                              3.44.0-7.el7_7                                                                                                        updates
nss-tools.x86_64                                                                                                                3.44.0-7.el7_7                                                                                                        updates
nss-util.x86_64                                                                                                                 3.44.0-4.el7_7                                                                                                        updates
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`yum updateinfo` lists the advisories for packages that can be updated. Am example output is:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.ate.info
 * epel: fedora.tu-chemnitz.de
 * extras: centos.mirror.ate.info
 * updates: ftp.rezopole.net
Updates Information Summary: available
   3 Security notice(s)
       1 Important Security notice(s)
       2 Moderate Security notice(s)
   1 Bugfix notice(s)
updateinfo summary done
```

On the other hand, `yum check-update` lists all the updates available for your packages.  These you would typically upgrade to only if you need the extra functionality, not for security reasons.